# Local min and differentiability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose there is a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

1. If $x^*$ is a local minimizer of $f$
   over $X$, must $x^*$ be either of the
   two cases:

   - if $f$ is differentiable at $x^*$, then $x^*$ must be a stationary point
     i.e.  $\nabla{f}(x^*)=0$
   - $f$ is non-differentiable at $x^*$?

   In other words, are there other
   possible cases for a local
   minimizer besides the two? I seem to have seen
   this as a conclusion from somewhere that I now
   cannot recall. However the following
   proposition seems to challenge this.
2. From p194 on [Nonlinear
   Programming](http://books.google.com/books?ei=UvV7TYHMAu-80QGBnOTQAw&ct=result&id=QeweAQAAIAAJ&dq=Bertsekas+nonlinear+programming&q=Proposition+2.1.2#search_anchor) by Dimitri P. Bertsekas:

   If $X$ is a convex set.

   > Proposition 2.1.2: (Optimality
   >   Condition)
   >
   > (a) If $x^*$ is a local minimum of $f$
   >   over $X$. then $$ \nabla{f}(x^*)'(x - x^*) > 0, \forall x \in X. $$
   >
   > (b) If $f$ is convex over $X$, then
   >   the necessary condition of part (a) is
   >   also sufficient for $x^*$ to minimize
   >   $f$ over $X$.

   If the conclusion in Part 1 is
   true, then if $f$ is
   differentiable at $x^*$, we will have
   $ \nabla{f}(x^*)=0$. Under this logic, I was confused
   why we have the proposition (a) as
   above in the book?

   How to interpret the proposition geometrically?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: @Tim: I *think* you wanted $\nabla$ when you typed `\grad`, correct? The LaTeX code is `\nabla`.

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks! Yes, and nice to learn about that.

Comment: I think it depends on how "local minimum" is defined. In general, a further condition is needed, e.g., that the local minimum be in the interior of $X$. Take $X = [0,1]$ and the function $f(x) = x$ to see why.

Comment: @cardinal: The definition for a point to be a local minimizer of a function is that there exists a neighbourhood of the point s.t. the function value at any point in the neighbourhood is always greater than or equal to that at the point. This implies that a local minimizer must be in the interior of the domain of the function.

Comment: @Tim, if your (sub)space is $X = [0,1]$, then what are the open sets over $X$? Then, what are the neighborhoods?

Comment: @cardinal: Thanks! When optimizing a function $f$ over  $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ which is specified by some constraints, is the neighbourhood in the definition of local min by default specified with respect to the restriction of the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $X$?

Comment: @Tim, you wrote "...s.t. the function value at any point in the neighborhood is always greater than or equal to that at the point." Doesn't the condition in 2.1.2 (a) imply the local minimum value of f is reached at a single point? For example, the function f(x) = 0 would not have a local minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimitri Bertsekas is right. Your conclusion 1 cannot hold in general because when $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and $x$ lies on the boundary of $X$, you are talking about a constrained minimizer. Note that $X$ must be closed for optimization to make sense. Consider for instance $X=[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = -e^x$.

The condition given in part (a) of Proposition 2.1.2 is that there exist no (first-order) feasible descent direction for $f$ from $X$. Note that the convexity of $X$ is assumed here.

In general, $x \in X$ is a constrained minimizer if, by definition, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y \in X$ such that $\|x-y\| < \epsilon$, you have $f(x) \leq f(y)$. This applies even if $f$ is not differentiable.

It's not difficult to show that if $f$ is differentiable, this implies that $-\nabla f(x)$ lies in the cone normal to $X$ at $x$. You'll find the definition of the normal and tangent cones, e.g., in the book by Bazaraa, Sherali and Shetty or pretty much any good optimization book. When $X$ is convex, this is exactly what part (a) of Proposition 2.1.2 says.